# Creating and Linking GUI in BeagleBone Black

Tags: python, ubuntu, user-interface, glade, beagleboneblack

I am creating a GUI application for running in Ubuntu 13.10 in Beagle bone black using GLADE. I am using python to programm the GPIO and other hardware functionalities of BBB.I drawn the windows and menus using Glade.I want to link my hardware program written in python to this GUI.ie if I click LED ON button it should be lighted on.So how can I link the GUI created using Python to my beaglebone program.Also i want the GUI to take some values as an input from the user.So i want to use this user input value to my hardware coding.How these are possible?

Answer (score 2):

I often recommend Derek Molloys videos. He shows how to build nice looking GUIs on BeagleBone Black to sense and control hardware using GPIO. His BeagleBone site has this address: http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/

He uses Qt for the GUI development in the videos on this page: http://derekmolloy.ie/beaglebone/qt-with-embedded-linux-on-the-beaglebone/

As you probably know, the GPIO interaction with the Beaglebone can be done by writing to the file system. If you open the file `brightness` related to one of the LEDs on the board, and write `0` to it, the LED will turn off. This is easily done in Python. In the videos Linux command line examples and C programming examples are shown, but the principles are the same for Python.

Sorry for not being able to answer the GLADE related parts of your question.